# ORACLE - SQL query to retrieve employees whose salary was increased during the last 6 month

Tags: sql, oracle, function

The table in question has the following structure:

```
Dec (1) | Jan (2) | Feb (3) | Mar (4) | Apr (5) | May (6) | Employee-ID | Amount
```

I need a query that would retrieve the records of those employees whose salary was increased during the last 6 months.

**NOTE TO THE OP**:
You wrote that it needs to be done using an *analytic* function. And it is not clear where the need of any analytic function is. The query that resolves your question is very straightforward.

Comment: Can you post the table structure with sample data?

Comment: Please provide sample data, expected output for that data, and explanation about that output you want.

Comment: You need to formalize your question, because current answer is just look at all employers and pick the ones with raised salaries

Comment: Your title is your opportunity to "sell" your question to people. *Everyone* here asking questions is seeking help and the *tags* tell us what technology is involved. If I remove the fluff and tags from your title, I'm left with nothing. Please [edit] your question and try to add a title that *describes* your question.

Comment: As per my understanding, you need all employees (customer_id) who had salary raise every month in last 6 months? Also it would be great if you can format the question

Comment: Excuse me for the misunderstanding created . The task assigned to me was:
  Create a query (on oracle sql) that will return all employees who have been raising they salary for the last 6 months. The solution must be created with analytics function. I also need to build the database structure by my self with Months, Employes_id, Amount columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try below query:

```
select customer_id 
from (
select customer_id , min(salary - previous_month_salary) salary_diff
from (
select customer_id , amount  as salary, months
,lag(amount,1,0) over (partition by customer_id order by months asc) as 'previous_month_salary'
from customer where months >= add_months(sysdate, -6)
)  t1 group by customer_id
)  t2 where salary_diff >0
```

> Subquery t1 fetches previous month salary (default value 0) of each
>   customer
>
> Subquery t2 calculates salary difference from previous month then the
>   minimum of salary difference.

Customers who had salary increase every month should have minimum salary difference greater than 0.

Comment: great to hear that. Could you please mark it as correct answer  and also an upvote would be appreciated :) ?